# React, styled-components - style inner styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jvbeh7

It's a simple react app using styled-components

I'm passing a prop `desktop`

```
<Block desktop>
    <InnerBlock />
</Block>
```

And I'm trying to style the inner style component when the prop is there

```
const Block = styled.div<IProps>`
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

  ${InnerBlock} {
    margin: ${p => p.desktop ? '10px' : null};
  }

`;
```

If I try this I get an error on `${InnerBlock}`

```
Block-scoped variable 'InnerBlock' used before its declaration.
```

Is it possible to style an inner styled-component `<InnerBlock />` when there is a prop on the parent

Answer (score 2):

Found the correct way.

```
const Block = styled.div<IProps>`
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

  ${InnerBlock} {
    ${(p) =>
      p.desktop &&
      css`
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: yellow;
    `};
  }

`;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if your code gets very complex, across many files, you can run into circular dependencies that are undefined at runtime. This is indeed the correct approach though.